# What does /opt mean in a filepath?

Tags: linux

I see so many file paths that have /opt in them from example code. Like this one:

`:staticfiles => "/opt/example/apps/example/static/"`

I would understand if it were something like `home`, but I don't know of any directory named opt.

What does it mean? Is it short for option or something? If it were `home`, since I'm on a Mac, I'd just change it to `Users`, but now I'm lost.

Comment: `/opt` is just another common top-level directory. OS X systems have `/opt`; I believe MacPorts installs itself into `/opt/local`. Unlike e.g. regexes, filesystem paths don't have any way of specifying other data—just the filepath. A regex might be expressed as something like `/[ab]c*/i` (the `i` after the slash making it case-insensitive); paths have no way of expressing any such thing. All you know is that each component is the name of a directory contained in the previous one, except the last (which may be a file).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649355/what-does-opt-mean-as-in-the-opt-directory-is-it-an-abbreviation

Comment: Have you tried doing `ls -ld /opt`? That's what I'd do if I was curious about a directory I'd never heard of before. Also check out [Wikipedia:Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Answer (score 4):

According to [THIS](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html) page, and this one [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), `/opt` is a directory reserved for

> Optional application software packages.

This means that if you were to install any application or package that doesn't come with the operating system itself, it should be installed somewhere in this directory.

This applies for most UNIX or UNIX-like operating systems, including Max OS X.

Comment: That's just convention, though. `/usr/local` is also a popular choice for things built from source or retrieved from places besides the package manager included with the OS, is it not? I know [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installs itself and its packages into `/usr/local`.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Yes, I absolutely agree. At the end of the day, it is only convention, and is up to the programmers personal preference.